# Loading image from localstorage and retaining it

Tags: javascript, tizen-web-app

I am working on a tizen web app were user have to select image from disk and then save it locally.I am able to load image from disk .But i have to retain the image there.When I go back from that page to another,the image is gone.The need is to save the image and display whenever I come to that page.When I alert the path,I'm getting as /opt/usr/media/images/file.jpg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the image to dataURI and store in localstorage. After that you can retrieve it from localstorage whenever you want to and then pass it to src of image tag to display the image. The webkit engine will take care of rendering the image from dataURI.

To save in local storage
localStorage.setItem("data", "datauriofimage")

To retrieve from localstorage
var srcImg = localStorage.getItem("data");

Comment: ya I've been using localstorage.But the prob was to use base64 before saving.

Comment: What issue you are facing in base64 before saving? Were you able to fix that?